# Constant value in Neyman Pearson lemma

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

To know the k value in Neyman Pearson lemma, do we need to know the alternate hypothesis. To what I understood (from articles like [PenStateNotes](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/307/)), we could get value of k using null hypothesis and the required significance level alpha.

[image]
I am asking this because in one of our internal academic document, it was specified that we need to know even the alternate hypothesis to get the value of k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a certain sense yes, you do "need to know" the alternative hypothesis, because in the Neyman-Person lemma it is required to compute the test statistic.

Specifically, let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from the (continuous) probability distribution $p_\theta(x)$, $\theta$ unknown. The likelihood function is $L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n p_\theta(x_i)$, where the $x_i$ are the observed sample values.

Suppose that you want to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$ against the alternative $H_1: \theta=\theta_1$ for some $\theta_0\neq \theta_1$. Then the Neyman-Pearson lemma tells you to use the test statistic
$T=L(\theta_0)/L(\theta_1)$. Note that to compute this, you need to know the value $\theta_1$ that defines the alternative $H_1$. Without knowing this, you could not compute $T$, and so not even $k$.